# Java error Attempt to mutate in notification

Tags: java, error-handling

I'm getting the error
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification` in some code I'm building off of [this site](http://www.cryptograms.org/play.php).

I made the GUI and I made a `documentListener` so the program will know when something has been put in the text fields. I get the error in the method `handleLetters`. It's supposed to work like the one in the link - when I put in a letter in I want to substitute with an `A` it puts the substitution letter in on all A's places if that makes sense?

I have tired googling but can't seem to get it to work with my code.

```
public GUI() {

    jp.setLayout(Layout);
    setTitle("Derp");
    System.out.println(size);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(700, 100);
    setResizable(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
    jp1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        char temp = SubstitutionCipher.newD.toString().charAt(i);
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
        if ((int) temp == 0) {

            textField.setBorder(null);
            textField.setEditable(true);
            jp1.add(textField);
            nums.add(textField);
            jp.add(jp1);
        } else {

            SubstitutionCipher.derp[i] = textField.getText();
            jp1.add(textField);
            nums.add(textField);
            jp.add(jp1);
            /* also store textField somewhere else. */
        }
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("remove");

                HandleLetters();

            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("update");
                HandleLetters();

            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Change");
                HandleLetters();
            }
        });
    }   
}

    jp.add(jb);
    add(jp);
}

public Runnable HandleLetters() {
    char[] charAry = new char[size];
    String[] k = new String[size];
    String[] temp = new String[size];
    int h;
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        charAry[i] = SubstitutionCipher.newD.toString().charAt(i);
        temp[i] = "d";
    }
    for (h = 0; h < charAry.length; h++) {

        k[h] = nums.get(h).getText();

        if (h == size - 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
                // System.out.println(k[i]);
                if ((k[i] == " ")) {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }//here i try to change recurring letters to the wished letter
    for (int i = 0; i < charAry.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("cnt: " + charAry[cnt]);
        System.out.println("i: " + charAry[i]);
        if (charAry[cnt] == charAry[(i + 1) % 21]) {
            System.out.println(k[cnt]);
            nums.get(i).setText("" + k[cnt]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SubstitutionCipher.SubstitutionCipher();
    GUI t = new GUI();
}
}
```

So I want to know what other Listeners can i use so my TextField will "know" that I put in a Letter, and the program is able able to change other letters.

Comment: Just as a note, dont know if it helps with your problem: you should initialize your gui through SwingUtilities.invokeLater as well

Comment: can you make it shorter? Focus in your problem.. but take care that you can't change your textfield in `documentListener`

Comment: Ya will edit the question a bit the thing is that I want the textfield to be editable by the program but at the same time I want it to "know" when letters are put in and deleted wich the documentListener does... ill delete some of the code and try to make it more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Windowbuilder. Will make it easier for you to control the UI.